# Probability theory book for self-sudy

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I want to know a book on Probability theory (Measure-theoretic) for self-study, like at the level of Terence Tao's analysis and measure theory book (he does not have any prob. th. book I guess).

I found P. Billingsley matching this criteria to some extent, but any book other than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have try the following 3 books:

- "A course in Probability theory" of Kai Lai Chung
- "Probability & Measure Theory" of Robert B.Ash and Catherine A. Doléans-Dade
- "Probability theory" of S.R.S.Varadhan, which is available to download here: https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/limittheorems.html

Comment: Oh my mistake. I've just updated. Thanks!